# When would a do...while(false) block with one condition make sense?

Tags: c

While working on a large existing source base, I found several instances of this construct:

```
do
{
    if (!a)
        break;
    something();
} while(false);
```

Under what scenario is that better than the (in my opinion) simpler

```
if (a)
{
    something();
}
```

?

There are tons of instances of this construct, so I assume it is intentional. Unfortunately, the person who wrote that code is not available.

Is there any reason why the first way of writing a block of code preferrable to the second one?

Comment: If I had to guess, someone saw this as a #define macro trick that would do some weird logic checking and got the wrong idea.

Comment: Oh, is it more like do{if(a) break; doA(); if(b) break; doB();} while(false);? Multiple logical breaks?

Comment: @leewangzhong: Some times, but most of the times it's not. It's just like I wrote above.

Comment: Is it possible that the original author was planning to change it to `if(a[i])` and `while(i < MAX)` later on, but wanted to make sure it worked for one item first?

Comment: Copied code and leaving room for restructuring?

Comment: @leewangzhong: Seems like the only sensible explanation. In fact I was thinking it would be more along the lines of getting more efficient machine code when compiling (this is not x86), but it seems that is not the case.

Comment: Writing tricky code can make it harder for compilers to optimize.

Comment: I wonder if the empty while yields better machine code than using gotos. I'd say it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decent analogy for this strategy is returning from a function; if this code were in a function, that "break" would be a "return false"; however, that's not possible here, since one cannot simply break out of an arbitrary code scope in C/C++.

Doing the "break" trick *prevents* nonsensical if-nesting as more and more sanity-check and failure conditions build up.  Yes, there are always more ways to do things, but often this strategy mirrors the normal thought-processes and workflow of functions, and people are often very familiar with that workflow.

It may even be the case that a function was moved *into* another area of code (perhaps because it was so specialized that it would never be reused), and it wasn't worth the effort to refactor the "return"-driven logic.

For example, this may be a more meaningful demonstration of the strategy.  I've included a less trivial setup to demonstrate why you might see this:

```
intenseStructure = allocate_memory_and_other_expensive_things();
do {
    if( ! some_test_of( variable1 ) ) {
        some_log( "Unexpected value for variable1." );
        break;
    }

    variable2 = some_thing_involving( variable1 );
    if( ! some_test_of( variable2 ) ) {
        some_log( "Unexpected value for variable2." );
        break;
    }

    something();
} while(false);
delete intenseStructure;
```

Here, let's assume that we can't meaningfully test "variable1" until we've set up "intenseStructure", and the same goes for "variable2" (which needs "variable1").  The "do...while(false)" strategy mirrors a function-based approach:

```
bool do_something( Intense* intenseStructure ) {
    if( ! some_test_of( variable1 ) ) {
        some_log( "Unexpected value for variable1." );
        return false;
    }

    variable2 = some_thing_involving( variable1 );
    if( ! some_test_of( variable2 ) ) {
        some_log( "Unexpected value for variable2." );
        return false;
    }

    something();
    return true;
}

intenseStructure = allocate_memory_and_other_expensive_things();
do_something( intenseStructure );
delete intenseStructure;
```

Here is an example of a more "traditional" if-oriented way.  As you can see, it is a bit more confusing, while behaving equivalently.  The nesting of the if-statements can become very troublesome and confusing after a while, and code maintenance can become quite difficult:

```
intenseStructure = allocate_memory_and_other_expensive_things();
if( ! some_test_of( variable1 ) ) {
    some_log( "Unexpected value for variable1." );
} else {
    variable2 = some_thing_involving( variable1 );
    if( ! some_test_of( variable2 ) ) {
        some_log( "Unexpected value for variable2." );
    } else {
        something();
    }
}
delete intenseStructure;
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand why you would want to do it with more than one condition, and logic between them. I'd use `goto` myself though... But my question is why would you like to do it with _one_ condition, as I wrote in the question. The code I posted, except for the names redacted is pretty much verbatim.

Comment: I would suspect that it would end up being due to habit or general procedure, in that case.  It might have been the (formal or informal) policy or convention to always do things like that in case future conditions needed to be added; this would avoid a significant restructuring of the code in that case.

Answer (score 5):

It's a way to implement `GOTO`  without explicitly using it.

Generally speaking, I believe C put `if` statements so that you can program in a [structured programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) paradigm.

That Wikipedia article notes a deviation from the paradigm would be early exit, which would be a use case for the `do while (false)`.  However, the suggested pseudocode to handle [early exit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Early_exit) still has a not-always-`false` condition in the `while` loop.

For the example of processing a file with errors, it notes that somebody might write it like this:

```
// open file
while (/* reading not finished */)
{
    // read some data;
    if (/* error */)
    {
        // stop the subprogram and inform rest of the program about the error;
        // use of break here would skip the "process read data" step
    }
    // process read data;
}
// finish the subprogram;
```

Comment: And when is that preferable to writing the normal `if`, or actually writing `goto` if that is what you want to do?

Comment: In C, I've seen one good use of `GOTO`, it is [releasing resources in the opposite order that you allocated them](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MEM12-C.+Consider+using+a+goto+chain+when+leaving+a+function+on+error+when+using+and+releasing+resources). I'm more of a C++ guy myself (we would use exceptions and RAII for the above example), so I know of no other places where I'd want to use `goto`, and thus, I can't think of any reason why `do { /* ... */ } while(false)` would be something I'd want to use.

Comment: That's definitely the best use case I've found for `goto`, though I've also seen it used effectively in hand-written parsers.

Answer (score 1):

if there are multiple break conditions & if it not possible to use switch then generally programmers use do while

```
do
{
   if (some  cond)
   {
     // do some job
      break;
   }
   else if (some cond)
   {
      // do some thing break
   }

   // similarly
}
while(false);
```

objective is to jump out of the loop after executing one or few conditions in do expression

Comment: And when is that preferable than writing a different function and break out with `return`? You can even inline it if you're very stack limited. Or use `goto`?

Comment: Function calls with lots of parameters? And you can't force inline.